# ASP.NET Using slash in alert()

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I would like to prompt the path of the excel file to the user. But I cannot include slashes in the alert function. Here goes my code that works:

```
Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder() 
sb.Append("<script type ='text/javascript'>window.onload=function(){alert('C:')};</script>")
```

However, because I need to alert user regarding the path, I need to put e.g. `C:\Program Files\New Folder`. But when I insert the slash '\' the `alert()` will not work. Please guide me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape the slash, like this:

```
'C:\\\\'
```

This is because slashes in strings are - in most languages - used to escape special characters, such as, for example, in a newline:

```
\n
```

So, if you need the slash to be written out verbatim, you need to escape the slash itself. You need to do this twice - once for C# to escape it and write out `'C:\\'` which will then be escaped by Javascript, producing `C:\` in your alert.

Alternatively, you can escape it once and use the "verbatim" modifier, which will treat the escape character as a literal backslash instead:

```
sb.Append(@"<script type ='text/javascript'>window.onload=function(){alert('C:\\')};</script>")
```

Comment: What if I wanted to add slashes for the alert when I am using xlWorkBook.Path instead of pre-defined path?

Comment: Try `xlWorkBook.Path.Replace(@"\", @"\\")` - this will double up all your quotes so they're escaped in the resulting JS.